# Receive input for Unity game over local port?

Tags: c#, networking, unityscript, unity-game-engine

How would I setup Unity to read in data over a port (say 127.0.0.1:54321), and use that input however I want. Basically, just read in the buffer as a string (or JSON) when ever something is sent to that port.

For example, I call:

```
$ curl -X PATCH -F "data=0.11,0.27,0.22,0.31,0.08,0.0" 127.0.0.1:54321
```

and I get the string:

```
"0.11,0.27,0.22,0.31,0.08,0.0"
```

In my unity script (currently using their java/unity script).

Comment: Look for: unity sockets *sorry didn't have time to write full answer yet, there's many tcp server/client examples available..

Comment: you can basically use any socket api (e.g. .NETs System.Net classes when using C#)